# Peculiar behaviour with Mac OS X Application on El Capitan

Tags: macos

I have an installation made with Packages (v1.1.3), and my application installs fine.

And I can run it ONCE. Second time, the application won't open. It is as if OS X thinks the application still is running, because if I start the application from terminal:

> open -n /Applications/MyApplication.app

it DOES open. But not without the -n option. And there is no instance of it running, either shown in Activity Monitor, or with ps -A.

Furthermore, starting the executable directly in a terminal:

> /Applications/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication

works just fine (!)

Also, if I logout, then log back in, the application will open normally.

I really have no idea where to look for the solution for this one...

Edit: Installation on 4 other machines (2 El Capitan and 2 Yosemite) does not exhibit this problem, which means it is located to one (my) installation only.

Edit 2: Unfortunately one more machine than mine exhibits the problem. Sigh....

Edit 3: If rename the application, to say "MyApplication2.app", the application opens directly, but if I rename it back, it won't start. So OS X must be caching something, somewhere. My El Capitan installation is an upgrade from Yosemite, same as the other machine experiencing this issue. Related ??

Comment: Sounds like you need to start logging stuff in order to find out what's bailing out and where.

Comment: As you probably can imagine, OS X is not my development platform... I'm right now looking at dtrace to see if there is anything left behind running the app the first time.

Comment: Running the installation on a new El Capitan and another Yosemite machine does not exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [apple.se] :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the application had a call to bootstrap_register, which resulted in the observed behaviour. With that call removed, everything started to work normally.